# Is it ok to keep constructing new Firebase refs or I should reuse?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm extremely new to Firebase. Naively, I would imagine it's ok to keep instantiating new Firebase refs that point to the same location and using them interchangeably.

However, I'm not sure if there are any subtleties around caching or other considerations I should be aware of that make reusing the same reference for the same Firebase location desireable/preferable over creating a new one.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105938/firebase-use-one-ref-for-an-object-and-push-onto-its-child-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668342/storing-multiple-firebase-references, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981708/firebase-reference-on-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166991/best-way-to-handle-firebase-references-with-android (I'm going to close as a duplicate of that last one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reuse old firebase ref instance when:
   if you only refer to one filebase app url during get/set data to server progress.
   Ex:

   public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   ```
             private Firebase firebaseRef; //declare unique refer instance for all code
             @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
                    super(bundle);

                    //other code here......
                    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
                    firebaseRef = new  Firebase("http://mydb.firebaseio.com/node");


          }
   ```

}

2. Create new firebase ref instance when:
   if use have plan to access to multi firebase app or multi nodes url then you can create a firebase instance at anytime, anywhare you want ref to them.

Ex:

```
Firebase firebaseFrefA = new Firebase("http://mydb.firebaseio.com/a");
Firebase firebaseFrefB = new Firebase("http://mydb.firebaseio.com/b");
Firebase firebaseFrefC = new Firebase("http://mydb.firebaseio.com/c");
Firebase firebaseFrefAU = new Firebase("http://mydb.firebaseio.com/a/u");
```

Note: firebase automaticly control all own's instance so you can free create new instance to use.